# Header will not display unless absolutely positioned

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I'm having a wee bit of an issue and I think it's probably my lack of knowledge about absolute positioning.

I have a div for a header that is full size and set to "background: cover". It is set to be 100% width and 90% height. However, the background will not display unless I set it to "position: absolute".

On top of this there is another div which behaves fine, whether a position is specified or not.

I'm sure this is probably just my lack of understanding of positions but I just can't get to the bottom of it.

This is the CSS for the header-div and the content on top of it.

```
#header-image {
    background: url(bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed #b6eedd;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
      width: 100%;
      height: 90%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      position:absolute;
      z-index: -999;
      display: block;
      float: left;
}


#front-content {
    margin-top: 3%; 
}

#front-content  {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    color: #f70035;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 90%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Thank you for any help.

On jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/SpeshalCrayon/nmc5X/6/

Comment: try to add position:relative; - z-index won't work if no position set

Comment: It won't display with position: relative. :(

Comment: create a demo on jsfiddle pls

Comment: It sounds like a [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) problem... We need to see how your markup is structured to help you.

Comment: Please show your html also

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't realise you'd need the html too! http://jsfiddle.net/SpeshalCrayon/nmc5X/ - there we go. Would it be easier if I hosted the images so you could see it with the images too?

Comment: Yes! since your problem is with a bg image, with img please!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SpeshalCrayon/nmc5X/6/ - there we go. Sorry for being a bit useless!

Comment: In your latest fiddle, you set the height of `#header-image` to `90%`, but as the parent, `#front` doesn't have a height set explicitly, the calculated height for `#header-image` becomes 0. If you also put `position:absolute`, it no longer has a parent, so it uses 90% of the height of the root, `html`. That is the reason it works with position, but not without.

Comment: However, you don't really want to use the `#header-image` without `position:absolute`. See what happens without position, if you set the height to, for instance, 200px instead of 90%. That's not what you want, is it? Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Yeah, I want it to change according to window size, so set pixel height doesn't really work.

Comment: @user3389724 That's not what I was referring to.